# CORS issue on AWS CDN with React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, grails, cors, cdn

I am trying to have a rest calls from deployed react app (AWS S3 CDN) to resource on grails application.

React app has ULR https://something.cloudfront.net/index.html

CORS configuration looks the same as on AWS [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/cors.html) except exemple.com of course.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-custom-header</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Grails app configuration (application.yml) looks like this:

```
grails:
  cors:
    enabled: true
    allowedOrigins:
    - "https://something.cloudfront.net"
```

With all this set, I get the message in the browser:

> Failed to load https://example.com/someResources: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'http://localhost:52449' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
>   Origin 'https://something.cloudfront.net' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

It really puzzles me why do I see **http://localhost:52449**? I have built the react application and copy the static file into the CDN, http://localhost:52449 is the address when react app is started locally with `npm start`.

React code for making the rest call looks like this:

```
axios.get<any>('https://example.com/someResources',
    {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
        },
    })
    .then((response) => 
        console.log(response);
    );
```

EDIT 1:

[image]

What am I doing wrong thus the CORS issue is still there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please paste the Network debugger Request/Response Headers?
Please make sure the 1-**Origin** which can be seen in the Request Header being sent out in the PreFlight Request Headers shall match the 1-"**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**". Also the HTTP Method you are invoking on request, header wise and verb wise 2-"**Access-Control-Request-Headers**" & 3-"**Access-Control-Request-Method**" shall conform to Response Header Params: 2-"**Access-Control-Allow-Headers**" and 3-"**Access-Control-Allow-Methods**" on the Response. Other wise the Pre-flight(OPTION) request will fail.

Maybe your browser is Caching the page. That's why if you trace back it from the Network Debug mode and not Console you can trace back the issue easier. 
[Pre-Flight Network Debugging on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLHtI.png)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a few days! React AWS API and CORs.

by this time I was using fetch and axios.

The answer was to take all the headers out. As everywhere says the headers are a server side thing. The error reported appears to be CORS / preflight and the solution lies in the Options process. I tried everything and this morning I deleted the API, rebuilt it with every option for CORS to be turned on and then stripped my code of headers and variables and instead loaded up a URL to see if I could bang that through and to see the type of errors I would get. None!  Here's the code:

```
axios.post(postUrl).then(
  (res) => {
    console.log('Axios:',res);
    console.log('Axios data:',res.data);
  }
).catch((err) => {
  console.log('Axios Error:', err);
})

fetch(postUrl, {
      method: 'POST'
    }).catch(error => console.log('fetch',error))
```

fetch worked 'naked' too. I prefer axios as results are consoled out with data. I did not work out if possible to do with fetch. I understand there are some gotchas with fetch to do with old browsers.

Where postUrl is the URL used for testing the API in the browser.

I now need to just write the code to build the URL dynamically and that should be easy. Famous last words...

Answer (score 0):

Permanently you can set AllowedOrigin to *

But you need to set a valid value according to your react app domain